# "select abc from (select 1) as abc" produces "(1)" instead of "1"

Tags: postgresql, alias

In Postgre, why does

```
select abc from (select 1) as abc
```

produces:

```
(1)
```

and

```
select * from (select 1) as abc
```

produces:

```
1
```

That's really strange to me. Is that the case with MySQL, Oracle, etc?
I spent hours figuring out why my conditions were failing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rows returned by your queries have different type: the first one is [`ROW(INT)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/rowtypes.html), while the second one is `INT`.

`MySQL` and others lack this feature.

In your first query, you are selecting a whole `ROW` as a single column. This query

```
SELECT abc FROM (SELECT 1, 2) abc
```

will produce `(1, 2)`, which is a single column too and has type `ROW`.

To select the `INT` value, use:

```
SELECT  abc.col
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS col
        ) abc
```